# Azure CRM dynamic 365 Tables modules column available backend but not available in power apps dataverse tables

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-synapse, dataverse

We are trying to pull the data from CRM using dataverse to connect synapse link to load the data into azure storage account.

we are facing issues, particular table option set sub column not visible and even it is not loading into azure storage schema and value.

if we checked in CRM SQL, the sub column and mapped data, we can able to see.

how to do we handle, i am not familiar MS CRM 365. kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

For your Dynamics CRM (Dataverse) tables to synchronize over Synapse Link to your Data Lake in Synapse:

1. The table needs to have "Track Changes" enabled. You do that in the advanced settings of the table, which you find in Power Apps. Sign into Power Apps and navigate to the Menu Dataverse>Tables. Click on the table and you find the advanced settings button.
2. Select the Table for synchronization in the Azure Synapse Link configuration. You do that from Power Apps as well but you need to wait a little after you activate "Track Changes"

[image]

3. Soon after you will find the files with the data in your data lake.